# Electrostatic request about forces of dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

So this question pertains to few different topics.

1. How to find the electrostatic potential due to the point charge placed outside of a dielectric? (- to understand the difference between $\textbf{D}$ and $\textbf{E}$ on a concrete example)
2. Exact formula for attractive force between point charge and dielectric of constant $\epsilon$. (That is the most important for me)
3. How do gauss law as $\oint{D.ds}=Q_{embedded}$ works for (two or more) different materials?

These are the assumptions

- dielectris is made up of vacuum ($\epsilon_0$) and dipoles.
- Total electrostatic charge of a dipole equals $0$.
- Electrostatic field (E) causes dipoles to polarise i.e. $\tau=p\times{E}$, and $p=ql$ is a dipole moment.
- Polarized dipole experiences force $F=p\nabla{E}$, but the distance $l$ also depends on the field $E$ as in hooke's law $l\sim\frac{qE}{k}$
- A potential due to a dipole approximates to $p\frac{cos(\theta)}{r^2}$

Now, google founds no results for "force between dielectric..." That there some force appears ought to be a noted effect. How to deduce the formula **that depends on ε of the material** and not some weird constants like $p$ from the first principles? Please can you post the formula for attractive force that a dielectric of constant $\epsilon$ experiences in field of $\textbf{E}$. Also how it relates to $\textbf{D}=\epsilon{\textbf{E}}$?

**Q. What is the formula for a force dielectric experiences in nonhomogeneous electric fields?**

Comment: too many questions/topics for on post.

Comment: @BobD please read the whole question, they are only supplements to main question. if you address the main problem they can be omitted

Comment: I tried to introduce the order in which these doubts appeared to me. Answer that poins out the force formula will be accepted

Comment: What exactly is the "main question"? It's not clear, to me anyway.

Comment: @BobD formula for the force dielectric experiences in nonhomogeneous electric field

Comment: Why not simply say that word for word. It's easier than trying to figure it out  from the rest of the post.

Comment: @BobD I edited it

Comment: OK, I have withdrawn my vote to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For electrostatics, you could generalize the dipole force formula as
$$
F = (P\cdot \nabla) E,
$$
where $P$ is the polarization density, and all quantities are vectors. This will result in a force density vector field (force per volume). Then, integrate over the dielectric volume to find the total force. If you have time-varying fields, you’ll also need the magnetic force term.

If you instead derive the force density via Gauss’ Law, you’d come up with
$$
F=-(\nabla\cdot P)E.
$$
You’ll notice that this is a different expression than the one above (and indeed the microscopic force density distribution is different). However, both expressions give the same *total* force acting on an object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. if D is not dependent upon material then $\frac{\epsilon-\epsilon_0}{\epsilon^2}(D\cdot\nabla)D$ would that formula hold for an isotropic material i substituted $D=\epsilon_0{E}+P$ to your relation

Comment: @konto I’m a little unclear what you mean by D not being dependent on material. But I suppose your relation would hold for an isotopic material.

Comment: I thought that D perpendicular to borders of a dielectric is independent of it. I just started to lern about other laws. At the time of writing this question i only knew gauss law, but $\nabla\times{E}=0$ needs to hold too!